# Realm - how to close realm instance with async transaction

Tags: android, asynchronous, realm

I have a problem with understanding what is good practice on closing Realm instance, whenever I am running async transaction.

In my application I have many controllers and I do not pass into them Realm instance from activity, instead I create a new one each time it is needed and close it as soon as work is done.

However recently I found out that it is not working correctly, if I am closing realm instance when it is running async transaction.

```
Realm cacheRealm = RealmDelegate.getCacheRealm();

cacheRealm.executeTransaction(realm -> {
    doSomeWork(response);
    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(response);
}, callback);
cacheRealm.close();
```

This code above has one big problem, that callback is never launched, since I am closing realm instance before transaction is finished.

Therefore I am not sure how am I supposed to handle this situation. Am I supposed to pass instance of Realm object into each controller from activity or fragment, and handle closing of realm instances only over there? Or maybe there are other more elegant solutions to this problem?

Also another thing that I am wondering about is what happens, if I won't close the Realm db, and is there a way to check if all instances of Realm has been closed?

Answer (score 5):

You can close the Realm in the callback instead? You have both an error and success callback to hook into: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#asynchronous-transactions

```
realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
            User user = bgRealm.createObject(User.class);
            user.setName("John");
            user.setEmail("john@corporation.com");
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // Transaction was a success.
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            // Transaction failed and was automatically canceled.
        }
    });
```

Comment: This has small problem, since I am constructing callback in other class, therefore I would need to create Realm instance over there. But I guess it is better than having one instance in Activity or Fragment.

As for second part of the question, is there any way to check if all instances were closed?

Comment: No, you can use `Realm.isClosed` but that will only check the instance on the current thread.

Comment: You can create another Callback and can call original call back passed from  other classes in the created Callback.

Comment: I encountered `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.` if I close realm in the `onSuccess` / `onError` callback.